# How to write OR query with elastic search in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, mean-stack

I have my document like this

Sample document,

```
    [
  {
    "_index": "xpertdox",
    "_type": "disease",
    "_id": "Ectopic Heartbeat",
    "_score": 24.650267,
    "_source": {
      "category": "Condition",
      "name": "Ectopic Heartbeat",
      "dui": "D005117",
      "url_name": "Extrasystole"
    }
  },
```

This is my sample document.

```
 if (req.param('disease')) {
searchString = req.param('disease');
filterQuery = { Category: 
   ['disease','Condition','speciality','pharm','medicine']  };


 } else if (req.param('docorhosp')) {
    searchString = req.param('docorhosp');
    filterQuery = { Category: ['hospital', 'doctor'] };
  } else if (req.param('speciality')) {
    searchString = req.param('speciality');
    filterQuery =  { Category: ['speciality'] };
  }
  client.search({
    index: 'xpertdox',
    type: 'disease',
    size: 20,
    body: {
      query: {
        must: {
          match: {
            name: {
              query: searchString,
              fuzziness: 2,
              operator: "or"
            }
          }
        },
        filter : {
          terms : filterQuery
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(function (resp) {
    var data = resp.hits.hits;
    if (isFromSsr) {
      data = helper.prepareSearchDataForSsr(data);
    }
    res.json(data);
  });
```

I am matching my parameter with name,but here I want to filter records only whose category is either 'doctor' or 'hospital'.How can devolope my query so to get my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.search({
    index: 'dox',
    type: 'disease',
    size: 20,
    body: {
      query: {
        must: {
          match: {
            name: {
              query: req.param('disease'),
              fuzziness: 2,
              operator: "or"
            }
          }
        },
        filter: {
          terms: {
            category: ['hospital', 'doctor']
          }
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: ,hi.How can I check the filter for the records other than hospital and doctor.I.e in the reverse way of my question.

Comment: Simply replace `filter` with `must_not`

Comment: filterQuery = must_not: { terms: { category: ['hospital', 'doctor']} };
7|xpertdox |                           ^
7|xpertdox | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: You don't construct the query correctly, I don't think you can simply shove `filterQuery` in there by reference. This is not an issue with ES, but your `filterQuery` definitions are not legal JavaScript

Comment: Ya I changed the query type no error but results are not getting fetched.

Comment: It's not the problem, this is not valid JS `filterQuery = filter: { terms: { category: ['speciality']} };` You must enclose the value inside curly braces too, i.e. `filterQuery = {filter: { terms: { category: ['speciality']} }};`

Comment: Show a sample document that you expect to be fetched. Also show your mapping, please

Comment: I have added in my question at the top

Comment: `Category` should be lowercase

Comment: Added sample document

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: Your field name is lowercase, so in your query you need to add the same field name, i.e. all lowercase `category` not `Category`

Comment: i.e. this `filterQuery =  { Category: ['speciality'] };` needs to be `filterQuery =  { category: ['speciality'] };`